# Restore Mysql database query is not working in ASP.NET, C#

Tags: .net, mysql

We are using Mysql.exe to restore database by the following query

```
string cmd ="-h" + ViewState["host"].ToString() + " " + "-u" + 
ViewState["user"].ToString() + " " + "-p" + ViewState["password"].ToString() + 
" " + ViewState["dbName"].ToString() + "<" + " " + 
Server.MapPath("BackupFiles/") + path;
```

The same query is executing in MySql command prompt but we are not able to restore using the above query in VisualStudio .Net, we have tried MysqlImport.exe to do the restore but it was no use. we are newbie to MySql if any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please update your question to include information on any error messages you received.

Comment: What are you doing with the `cmd` variable? are you starting a new process? please post more of the code, and explain what doesn't work.

Comment: Dear Will Hughes, Thanks for your reply, actually the same cmd is executing in command prompt, but in dotnet we are not getting any errors

Comment: Dear Meister, Thanks for your reply, using that cmd variable we are starting new process(mysql.exe). the same is working in command prompt but in dotnet not executing and also we are not getting any errors.here is the complete code please help me.

Comment: Dear Meister, Thanks for your reply,here is the complete code please help me.String path1 = Server.MapPath("BackupFiles/") + path; StreamReader file = new StreamReader(path1);
string cmd = string.Format(@"C:\EXE\mysql.exe -u{0} -p{1} -h{2} {3} < {4} ", '"' + ViewState["user"].ToString() + '"', '"' + ViewState["password"].ToString() + '"', '"' + ViewState["host"].ToString() + '"', '"' + ViewState["dbName"].ToString() + '"', '"' + path1 + '"');

Comment: ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TFGRS1\PostgresDLLS\mysql.exe", @"/C " + cmd);                                       proc.Arguments = cmd;
proc.UseShellExecute = false;
string res;
Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo = proc;
            p.Start();
            res = file.ReadToEnd();
            p.WaitForExit();

Comment: Dear Meister, we have tried that also but it was no use

Answer (score 0):

you are passing extra parameters

Try:

```
 ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\TFGRS1\PostgresDLLS\mysql.exe", cmd);
 Process p = new Process();
 p.StartInfo = proc;
 p.Start();
 p.WaitForExit();
```